# Creating continuous functions - topology

Tags: general-topology

I am having some difficulty in understanding the following proof.

--

If $X$ and $Y$ is a topological space, and there is a continuous function $f:X \to Y$. 
Now if $Z$ is a subspace of $Y$ containing the image set $f(X$), then $g:Z \to Y$ obtained from $f$ is continuous function.

Proof:

Clearly $f(X) \subset Z \subset Y$. Also let $B$ be an open set in $Z$. The we can express $B=Z\cap U$, where $U$ is an open set in $Y$.

As $Z$ contains the image set $f(X)$, by elementary set theory,

${f^-}^1(U) = {g^-}^1(B)$, which clearly is an open set and hence the new function is continuous .

Now I am having trouble understanding elementary set theory part, by which elementary set theory you can say the that the inverse of $f$ in $U$ is the same as inverse of $g$.

Would be grateful for clarification.

Comment: It's not "the inverse", it's the preimage. $f^{-1}(A) = \{ x : f(x) \in A\}$. Since $f(X)\subset Z$, we have $f(x) \in U \iff f(x) \in U\cap Z$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$g:Z\rightarrow Y$ obtained from $f$"?